# In NixOS, is there any way to create a package that has pandoc, pandoc-citeproc, and pandoc-crossref?

Tags: nixos, haskell, pandoc

I'm very new to NixOS. I use Pandoc a lot, often with `pandoc-citeproc`, but I can't find a NixOS package for `pandoc-citeproc`. I see that there's a Haskell library for pandoc-citeproc in `HaskellPackages`. How can I combine a Pandoc binary which is installed system-wide with a Haskell library?

Comment: The Nix package for `pandoc-citeproc` is marked as an executable and a library. Also, the package depends on pandoc. Do you get the `pandoc-citeproc` executable when you install the package?

Comment: Ah, I see. Pandoc-citeproc is in haskellPackages. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I got this working by adding these lines to `environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [`:

```
pandoc
haskellPackages.pandoc-citeproc
haskellPackages.pandoc-crossref
```

Still working on getting pandoc-crossref.